# Android menu with dividers and labels

Tags: android, xml, menu

can I add a divider and items (labels) that is not selectable to my PopUp meny xml.

If want a meny like this

```
Label1
------------- (divider)
RadioButton1
RadioButton2
------------- (divider)
Item1
Item2
------------- (divider)
Item3
```

I create my popup menu with

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener((PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener) this);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();
```

Im using this xml for my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".ComicBoothActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/Label1" android:title="Label1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Divider1" android:title="" android:showAsAction="always" android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_divider" />
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/RadioButton1"
            android:title="RadioButton1"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/RadioButton2"
            android:title="RadioButton2" />
    </group>
    <item android:id="@+id/Divider2" android:title="" android:showAsAction="always" android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_divider" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Item1"
        android:title="Item1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Item2"
        android:title="Item2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Divider3" android:title="" android:showAsAction="always" android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_divider" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Item2"
        android:title="Item2" />
</menu>
```

And the divider layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/orange08">

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make the label "unselectable", i.e that nothing happens when you click it and the menu stays open. Is this possibe? The divider layout is not showing. Its only a empty item entry in the menu. What have I missed? Or is there a better way to add dividers?

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:title="unselectable">
   <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share"/>
   </menu>
</item>
```